# Android NDK suddenly very slow

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

So I've return some code using android's NDK to parse information from some files and then write it to a database. Just recently I saw an update for the NDK so I updated it to the latest version (from 16 to 17) ever since then a process that used to take 2 seconds at most for 500 files now takes like 45 to 60 seconds. Has anyone every experienced this before and know of a potential fix or maybe what's causing the problem?

Comment: is that on Windows?

Comment: @AlexCohn yeah I'm using Windows 10, but I'm running the app on my Pixel 2